# I have a Login Loop only in XFCE

Tags: login, lightdm, xfce

I know there are many similar posts already, but none solved my issue. I've tried:

- renaming/removing .Xauthority
- removing/re-installing/reconfiguring lightdm
- switching to gdm

I've looked into xsession-errors, but found nothing there. Only after uninstalling lightdm and re-installing gdm3, which finally allowed me to login through a different DE, but when I come back to entering in XFCE (which is my preferred environment) it loops again! I was using Ubuntu Studio 18.04
Please help.

Comment: Ha, thought I'd answered a similar question recently ([here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1123476/527350)).  Seriously, have you had a look at the answers on that post? There are a lot of possibilities to try out there.  Welcome to the site, by the way!